# Rails 5 Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After some coding got this error on running `rails s`:

```
Address already in use - bind(2) for "127.0.0.1" port 3000 (Errno::EADDRINUSE)
```

My environment is:

```
$ rails -v       
Rails 5.0.0
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
```

I've tried:

1. Create a new project - the same
2. Checked Rails 4.2 - problem **solved**
3. Reinstall rails 5 and ruby - the same problem
4. `lsof -wni tcp:3000` returns me nothing
5. ps aux | grep "rails" - nothing
6. ps aux | grep "puma" - nothing
7. ps aux | grep "ruby" -nothing
8. Use `puma` instead of `rails s` - problem **solved**
9. Use `rails s -p 3001` - same problem, for other ports too

UPDATED

9. Use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails s` - problem **solved**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appeared because of a bug in Puma's code. Downgrading to the oldest version helped me.

Bug ticket: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1022

Answer (score 15):

The same process is running somewhere

To see which process used 3000 port and get the process pid type below command

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

This will give the process which is using this port

**Sample result**

```
process1   12345   0.0  0.0  12343566  1972 s000  R+   11:17AM   0:00.00 grep puma
```

You can kill this process by typing below command

**12345** this is the process ID

```
kill -9 12345
```

Now start server again

Comment: It was a bug in the code. Already not an issue for ~1.5 years.

Comment: Using `lsof` showed the processes when `ps ax` did not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What your error is saying is that there is something already running on port 3000. Without knowing more about your environment or what you have installed, it's impossible to know what to stop.

It's highly likely that another rails server is already running somewhere. Try going to localhost:3000 to see what's there.

It's possible that another program is piggybacking on this port for some unknown reason, if so and you can't stop it, use a differnt port

`rails s -p 3001`

or any other port you choose

Comment: I've tried that. Nothing. rails s -p 3001 returns same error.

Comment: Please read steps that I've done. Production environment is working ok (step 9) so now I'm really disappointed